# Xcode How to update Facebook sdk

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook

How can I update Facebook SDK? I have SDK version 4.1 and I want to update it to last version. I tried to remove SDK from my projects framework. Then I downloaded new SDK from [url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) and added new files to Framework folder:
FBSDKCoreKit.framework
FBSDKLoginKit.framework

Then I tried build my application and I had an error: FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)' does not contain bit code

I think I did something wrong. I can't disable Bitcode in my projects, because now it is necessary to publish the application in the iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Cocoapods you can `Disable Bitcode` for all the libraries using below commands in `Podfile`

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

---

If you want to disable bitcode in Xcode follow the below steps:

**Project>Build Settings>All>Build Options>Enable Bitcode = NO**

Answer (score 0):

Please turn off your bit code in your project, no problem while publish the application in the iTunes.

Comment: Use to it wasn't problem, but today it is necessarily